# boost spirit with alternative operator '|' Fail! when there are two possibles rules to go

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I am working on a http parser. It found a promblem when I try to parse using alternative operator. it is not about the values in attribute that I can fix them using hold[]. The problem occurs when there are two rules that are similar in the beginning of the 
rule. here are some simple rules to demonstrate my problem;

```
qi::rule<string_iterator> some_rule(
        (char_('/') >> *char_("0-9")) /*first rule accept  /123..*/
      | (char_('/') >> *char_("a-z")) /*second rule accept /abc..*/
    );
```

Then I parse this rule using `qi::parse` it will fail if the input string likes;
`"/abcd"`

However when I switch the second rule before the first rule. The parser will return true
I think the problem is because when the parser consume the input with the first rule
and then it finds that the first rule is Fail. It wont return to the second rule which is
an alternative of the first rule.

I try to put `hold[]` to the first rule but it only helps for generating an attribute. It
doesn't fix this problem. I have no idea how to fix this problem since HTTP have a lot of
rules that they have the beginning of the rules are same as others.

---

===========more info about my code============================
here is my function for parsing a string

```
typedef std::string::const_iterator string_iterator;
typedef qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rules_t;
void parse_to_string(const std::string& s, rules_t& r, std::string& result)
{
    using namespace rule;
    using qi::parse;

    std::string::const_iterator iter = s.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = s.end();

    bool err = parse(iter, end, r, result);

    if ( err && (iter==end) )
    {
           std::cout << "[correct]" << result << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
          std::cout << "[incorrect]" << s << std::endl;
          std::cout << "[dead with]" << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In main I have this code;

```
std::string result;
result = "";
str = "/htmlquery?";
qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rule_wo_question( char_('/') >> *char_("a-z"));
qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rule_w_question( char_('/') >> *char_("a-z") >> char_('?'));
qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> whatever_rule( rule_wo_question
                                                        | rule_w_question
                                                       );
parse_to_string(str, whatever_rule, result);
```

I get this result;

[incorrect]/htmlquery?
[dead with]/htmlquery           <= you can see it cannot consume '?'

however when I switch the rule like this; (I put "rule_w_question" before "rule_wo_question")

```
std::string result;
    result = "";
    str = "/htmlquery?";
    qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rule_wo_question( char_('/') >> *char_("a-z"));
    qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rule_w_question( char_('/') >> *char_("a-z") >> char_('?'));
    qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> whatever_rule( rule_w_question
                                                            | rule_wo_question
                                                           );
    parse_to_string(str, whatever_rule, result);
```

The output will be;
 [correct]/htmlquery?

The first verions (wrong one) seems like the parse consume '/htmlquery' ("rule_wo_question")and then it finds that it cannot consume '?' which make this rule fail.
Then this rule cannot go to an alternative rule ("rule_w_question") . Finally the program return "[incorrect]"

The second version I switch the "rule_w_question" before "rule_wo_question". This is the reason why the parser return "[correct]" as a result.

---

==============================================================
my whole code with boost 1.47 linked with pthread and boost_filesystem
here is my main .c

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/network/protocol.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_uint.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::string::const_iterator string_iterator;
typedef qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rules_t;
void parse_to_string(const std::string& s, rules_t& r, std::string& result)
{
    using qi::parse;

    std::string::const_iterator iter = s.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = s.end();

    bool err = parse(iter, end, r, result);

    if ( err && (iter==end) )
    {
           std::cout << "[correct]" << result << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
          std::cout << "[incorrect]" << s << std::endl;
          std::cout << "[dead with]" << result << std::endl;
    }
}





int main()
{
    std::string str, result;
    result = "";
    str = "/htmlquery?";
    qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rule_wo_question( char_('/') >> *char_("a-z"));
    qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> rule_w_question( char_('/') >> *char_("a-z") >> char_('?'));
    qi::rule<string_iterator, std::string()> whatever_rule( rule_wo_question
                                                           | rule_w_question
                                                           );
    parse_to_string(str, whatever_rule, result);
    return 0;
}
```

the result is

```
[incorrect]/htmlquery?

[dead with]/htmlquery
```

Comment: Could you post your grammar in EBNF form, please? It helps greatly in seeing any mistakes and also in determining if the grammar you propose is even supported by Spirit (i.e. LL(0)).

Comment: Your code snippet above looks ok, therefore something else is wrong. Please post a minimal self-contained code example exposing your problem.

Comment: could anyone help me. I posted the full version of my code. I really need help! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Spirit tries given alternatives in the sequence they are specified and stops parsing after it matched the first one. No exhaustive matching is performed. If one alternative matches it stops looking. IOW, the sequence of alternatives is important. You should always list the 'longest' alternatives first.

Comment: The longest (`"aaab" | "aab" | "aa"`) *or* the most specific (`'?' | +char_`)

Comment: Excellent question, and I must admit there is no straight answer to it. 'Most specific' seems to be correct most of the time, but in other cases 'longest match' appears to be right. To answer this question in any particular case you probably need to keep in mind how alternatives are evaluated in Spirit. It always evaluates alternatives top down, stopping at the first matched alternative.

Comment: my remark was actually intended as a refinement - _the question mark might have worked subliminally_. Indeed, like in all regular automaton, branch ordering is important.

Comment: from my example. when the string "/htmlquery?" is parsed with the rule " '/' >> *char_("a-z") which makes this rule "fail". However from your answer the parse should use the alternative rule (/ >> *char_("a-z") >> '?') but it doesn't. Finally the parser return false for the whole systems. I am not sure why the parser doesn't go to the alternative rule since the first rule is fail. Thank you

Comment: As I said above, I would need to see the whole example to figure out what's failing - preferrably a minimal example reproducing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks hkaiser. I post the whole code above. I use boost 1.47 in linux. very appreciated your help. Theparitt

Comment: @hakiser Thanks again. sorry that I keep posting messages. I understand that I have to use more specific rule first in order to "match" the topmost one. however my problem is different. The string doesn't match the first rule and also ignore the second rule when half of input string is already parsed. I can change the rules but it is quite hard and too complex to renew all the rules. I just follow the http standard. Thank you for your help again. theparitt

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you don't do this instead?

```
some_rule(
     char_('/')
     >> (
         *char_("0-9")  /\*first rule accept /123..\*/
       | *char_("a-z") /\*second rule accept/abc..\*/
     )
);
```

**Edit:** Actually that would match `/` followed by empty ("0-9" 0 times) and won't bother looking for "a-z", change `*` to `+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
qi::rule<string_iterator> some_rule(
    (char_('/') >> *char_("0-9")) >> qi::eol /*first rule accept  /123..*/
  | (char_('/') >> *char_("a-z")) >> qi::eol /*second rule accept /abc..*/
);
```

Instead of `eol` you could use ',' or some other terminator. The problem is that `char_('/') >> *char_("0-9"))` matches '/' followed by 0 or more numbers. So "/abcd" matches the "/" and then stops parseing. K-ballo's solution is the way I would do this case, but this solution is provided as an alternate in case (for some reason) his is not acceptable.

Comment: yep. I tried your solution and it didn't work. I tested with rule_w_question and rule_wo_question (you can see from the last part of my questions I've just posted it)    by appending qi::eol to the end of the rules. It seems the parser won't invoke any alternative rules when I used "Kleen star" with the rule that has some parts of the input are already consumed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is a match for your first rule, and Spirit is greedy.

```
(char_('/') >> *char_("0-9"))
```

Feeding "/abcd" into this rule will result in the following logic:

- "/abcd" -> Is '/' the next character?  Yes.  Subrule matches. -> "abcd" remains.
- "abcd" -> Are there 0 or more digits? Yes.  There are 0 digits.  Subrule matches.  -> "abcd" remains.
- First clause of alternative ('|') statement matches; skip remaining alternative clauses. -> "abcd" remains.
- Rule matches with "abcd" remaining.  Which probably then doesn't parse and causes your failure.

You might consider changing the '*', which means "0 or more", to a '+', which means "1 or more".